# Roof: Must the entire rake be replaced if the bottom end has rot?

Tags: framing, roof

On my roof a rake comes down and lands on the top plate where a valley rafter also lands. A lot of water flows down the roof to this point. At some point in time it found a leak. It didn't help that the previous owner put no flashing in the valley. So now all three pieces, the plate, the valley rafter, and the rake, have rot in them where they meet. No big deal if just the plate as that's replaceable, and the valley rafter is not in bad shape. But I was able to push a screwdriver a full inch into the bottom of the roof rake. Are there techniques whereby the rake, 90% of which is fine, can be saved? Some sort of patch or reinforcement method?

Comment: You need to cut out the rot plus some some extra good wood and replace with a similar size piece.  Doing it in place will probably be a PITA than removing the whole piece and replacing.

Comment: @crip659 Does all rtten wood have to be removed? I figure it won't infect adjacent pieces.  It's water that's the problem. I ask because given the location, actually cutting it out will be much more challenging than sistering in a reinforcement.

Comment: It should be all removed since there are living micro organsions in it that might spread. There are chemicals and sealers you could use that are supposed to stop rot.